# Riemannian submanifolds of Euclidean space admitting Lipschitz extension of Lipschitz functions, and converse statement

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ be a Riemannian submanifold. In what follows, when we talk about a Lipschitz function $f$ on $M$, namely $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$, we will assume there is a $L > 0$ so that:

$$  \lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert \leq Ld_M(x,y)\quad \forall x, y \in M.  $$

**My question is:** What is either a **necessary and sufficient** condition (preferred) *OR* if not possible, then at least a **sufficient** condition that every Lipschitz function on $M$ can be extended to a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^p$? So to write mathematically, what is or are sufficient condition(s) on $M$ so that for every Lipschitz $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists an extension $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ so that $\tilde{f}$ is also Lipschitz (possibly with a bigger Lipschitz constant)?

On the other side, what is a **necessary and sufficient** condition on $M$ so that every Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^p$ restricts to a Lipschitz function on $M$? I feel like for a compact manifold, this will be true, as there we will have:

$$C_1\lVert x- y\rVert \leq d_M(x,y) \leq C_2\lVert x-y\rVert,$$

because the exponential map is smooth, so the norm of its gradient will have an upper and a lower bound on compact $M$, resulting in the above inequality. *Is it true though?*

Comment: For future reference, it's "Lipschitz"; I have edited accordingly.  I also changed "sufficient or necessary and sufficient" to just "sufficient".

Comment: No problme with Lipscitz, thanks. May I ask why are you editing the necessary and sufficient part? It'd be nice to have an equivalent condition, no?

Comment: I agree, but asking for a condition that is sufficient or necessary and sufficient is the same as asking for a condition that is sufficient (and may also be necessary).  If you think it makes it clearer, then please feel free to put it back in.

Comment: @LSpice OKay. Sorry but I'm most happy with necessary and sufficient, slighly less happy with sufficient. So I'm putting it back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say $M$ admits universal Lipschitz extension if, for any Lipschitz $f : M \to \mathbb R$, there exists Lipschitz$F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $F|_M = f$. $M$ admits universal Lipschitz extension if and only if there exists $C$ such that $d_M(x,y) \leq C \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in M$ (note that it always holds that $\|x-y\| \leq d_M(x,y)$).

In the forward direction, suppose $d_M(x,y) \leq C \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y \in M$. Let $f : M \to \mathbb R$ be $L$-Lipschitz with respect to $d_M$. Then $f$ is $CL$-Lipschitz with respect to the Euclidean metric on $M$, and therefore by McShane's theorem, the function
$$F(x) = \sup\{f(y) + CL \|y-x\| : y \in M\}$$
is $CL$ Lipschitz and extends $f$.

For the other direction, suppose without loss of generality that $0 \in M$. Let $\mathcal L_M$ be the Banach space of Lipschitz functions $f$ on $M$ (Lipschitz with respect to $d_M$) such that $f(0) = 0$, equipped with the norm $\|f\|_{\mathcal L_M}  = \text{Lip}(f)$. Let $\mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}$ be the Banach space o\f Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the Lipschitz norm $\|f\|_{\mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}}$. The restriction map $R : \mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n} \to \mathcal L_M$, where $R(F) = F|_M$, is $1$-Lipschitz. Provided that $M$ admits universal Lipschitz extension, $R$ is surjective, and so by the open mapping theorem  there exists $C \in (0,\infty)$ such that for any $f \in \mathcal L_M$, there exists $F \in \mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}$ such that $RF = f$ and $\|F\|_{\mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}} \leq C \|f\|_{\mathcal L_M}$. Now, suppose for contradiction that there exist $x_n,y_n \in M$ such that $d_M(x_n,y_n) \geq n \|x_n - y_n\|$. The function $f_n(y) = d_M(x_n,y) - d(x_n,0)$ is in $\mathcal L_M$ with $\|f_n\|_{\mathcal L_m} = 1$, but for any $F \in \mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}$ with $R F = f_n$, $$\|F\|_{\mathcal L_{\mathbb R^n}} \geq \frac{|f_n(y_n) - f_n(x_n)|}{\|x_n - y_n\|} = \frac{d_M(x_n,y_n)}{\|x_n - y_n\|}\geq n.$$

Comment: Open mapping theorem guarantees boundedness from below only for injections. I think you should instead of $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbf{R}^n}$ consider $\mathcal{L}_{(M,\|\cdot\|)}$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course. Edited.

Comment: @Justthisguy Thank you for the answer! Quick question tio brush up my geometry: in the last line of the first paragraph of your answer, you wrote: "note that it always holds that $∥x−y∥≤d_M(x,y)$". Why is it true?

Comment: The distance on $M$ is the inf of the lengths of paths in $M$ connecting $x$ and $y$. The distance in $\mathbb R^n$ between $x$ and $y$ is the inf over the lengths of paths in $\mathbb R^n$ connecting $x$ and $y$, so it is in the inf over a  larger set and therefore bounded above by $d_M(x,y)$.

Comment: @Justthisguy Thanks, but these two lengths of paths are w.r.t. different Rielannian metrics, namely induced Riemannian metric on the manifold $M$ versus the canonical Euclidean matric in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so, sorry but I'm not sure how the larger set arguments go through? For a positively curved part of the manifold, path lengths or distances will increase from the Euclidean lengths/distances, but for the part that's negatively curved, the distance will decrease from the Euclidean distance, no?

Comment: The Riemannian metric on $M$ is the restriction of the Euclidean metric to the tangent space of $M$. Infinitesimally, the distances are equal, and so they give the same answer for the lengths of paths. That is, for any $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$, $|\gamma'|$ is the same whether you view $\gamma$ as taking values in $M$ or taking values in $\mathbb R^n$, and the length of $\gamma$ is just $\int\limits_0^1 |\gamma'(t)| dt$.

Comment: @Justthisguy Thanks, but then by what you wrote (" |γ′| is the same whether you view γ as taking values in $M= M^d$ or taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$"), for every $v \in T_p{M^d}$ with co-ordinate vector w.r.t. a basis again dented by $v$,  we'll have: $||v||^2_{\mathbb{R}^d} = v^{T}Av $ where $A$ is a symetric, positive definite matrix that represent the symmetric positive definite bilinear form on $T_p{M}$ that's the restriction of the innner product on $T_p{M}$. Sorry but I don't see why that's true? Why would the Euclidean norm of a vector and the inner product norm of a vector coincide?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105170/discussion-between-justthisguy-and-lets-talk-math).

Comment: @Justthisguy sure sent you a message in private chat if you so prefer, but I don't see the LaTeX symbols compiling there.